# How to know user agent for http request

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, request, user-agent

How can I know http request is from ipad or window tablet or andriod table or window desktop in asp.net vb.net MVC 3.

Comment: If you are sending a http request, the server needs to know that, not you. So have to send a valid user-agent to server along with your http request.

Comment: I mean the user request to www.my.com from ipad, I would like to know that request from ipad in server side.

Comment: Watch the `User-Agent` request header on the server for that. In asp.net I think its `var userAgent = Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString();`